# Alimentar Campo Hidden via JQuery

Tags: jquery

Como eu faço para mandar um valor para um campo Hidden via Jquery?

Preciso mandar uma posição do array para ele.

Comment: Ele tem um id ou um name?

Comment: Sim tem id e name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da mesma forma que outro campo qualquer:

Você pode pegar pelo id:

```
$(function(){
    $('#id_campo').val(id_array);
});
```

Pelo nome:

```
$(function(){
    $("[name='nome_campo']").val(id_array);
});
```

Ou pela classe:

```
$(function(){
    $(".classe_campo").val(id_array);
});
```